# Getting MPEG-TS output from AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetwriter, mpeg2-ts

Is it possible to mux audio and video together from an `AVCaptureSession` into an MPEG-TS stream? The documentation suggests a delegate for pulling the raw [video](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutput) and [audio](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureaudiodataoutput) and then this [post](https://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/capturing-video/) suggests that I might be able to do it with an `AVAssetWriter`, however instantiating

```
AVAssetWriter(contentType: .mpeg2TransportStream)
```

results in

```
[AVAssetWriter initWithContentType:] Invalid file type UTI.  Available file types are: public.aiff-audio, public.3gpp, public.aifc-audio, com.apple.m4v-video, com.apple.m4a-audio, com.apple.coreaudio-format, public.mpeg-4, com.microsoft.waveform-audio, com.apple.quicktime-movie, org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio'
```

Is there another path to extracting an MPEG-TS stream?

Comment: It's possible, but `AVAssetWriter` won't do it for you. You have to do it yourself.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman is there a way to extract the elementary streams?

Comment: You can encode h264/aac and mux the stream yourself. Or involve `libav` I guess.